# Why are TCP messages in my PC coming in frames of 590 bytes

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols, wireshark

I am analyzing wireshark log files, when I make a request to a web page using firefox through a proxy server.

Following are details of connection establishment:

1. I have noted "maximum segment size" when I open options branch in the TCP segment details of the [SYN] message from my PC to the proxy server - it says 1460 bytes
2. Similarly, maximum segment size eof  the [SYN,ACK] message from the proxy server to my PC - it says 1460 bytes

After establishing the TCP connection, should not each of the TCP frames sent from proxy server to my PC be of 1460 bytes? I am puzzled that why are they 590 bytes. Please advice how the 590 size is being set

Answer (score 4):

A plausible explanation is that 590 turns out to be the ***Path MTU*** for the particular connection.

In other words whereby the client (one of the end nodes of the connection)accepts packets of a maximum of of 1460 bytes payload, some node(s) on the way accepts smaller packets.  For efficiency purposes, the Path MTU Discovery allows the originator of a packet to size it so that it would fit the smaller MTU encountered on the path, and hence avoid fragmentation.

BTW:
 1460 is a very common MTU (well MSS), because it it corresponds to 1500, Ethernet v2's maximum, minus 20+20= 40 bytes for the IP header overhead)

See the following [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) for an overview of MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) and a basic description of the Path MTU Discovery method (Basically setting the the DF i.e. do-not-fragment flag and relying on the ICMP ""Destination Unreachable (Datagram Too Big)" messages to detect that some node on the way couldn't handle the packet, and hence try with smaller size until it goes through).

Also, I suggest inspecting the packets when the connection is to a different host, maybe a peer on the very same network segment, without going through the proxy mentioned.  Chances are you will then start seeing 1460 bytes frames.

Comment: thanks a lot for the information.exactly as you mentioned, i am seeing 1460 byte frames when i launch an intranet website. i suspected that intranet website is taking a different router, but it is using the same router as the proxy server. (i checked it with tracert command)