# Why are my TCP packet sizes 590 bytes instead of 8000+

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

Currently I've configured 2 PC's 10 GbE network cards to use an `MTU` of 9014 (Jumbo). 
Both PC's are then connected to a 10GbE switch. Both ports on the switch that the hosts are physically connected to have been configured for jumbo frames (9014). There are no other devices connected to the switch.

Both PC's however have 2 network cards. One card is 10GbE while the other is 1GbE. The 10GbE interface on both PC's are connected to the switch with a 10 based IP address. The 1GbE cards on both PC's are connected to the company LAN so that I can remote into either PC (they use a 172 based IP address, and they're not configured for jumbo frames).

If I ping from one PC to another on the 10 based address jumbo frame 10GbE network using `ping -l 8000 ipaddress` I can see via wire shark that the `ICMP` packet size is ~8000, which is what I would expect.

**Problem**

I have a little `TCP` server application running on one of the PC's (Windows 7 Embedded) written in `C#`. There is nothing special about that application, all it does is read the data and discards it. I'm using it purely to test network transmission speeds. I can post the server code if someone would find it interesting but its pretty basic.

On the other PC (Windows 10 Pro) I have another `C#` application which sends 100's of `GB`'s worth of data across the wire to the `TCP` server application for testing. Below is a very simplified example of how I'm sending the data.

```
using var tcpClient = new TcpClient( );
await tcpClient.ConnectAsync( address, port );

var pageSize = 25165824;
var pageHeaderSize = 312;

// For this example I'm sending about 24 MB chunks of data.
// This is the smallest 'chunk' that'll be sent.
var buffer = new byte[ pageSize + pageHeaderSize ];
var pageCounter = 0;

while( pageCounter < pageCount )
{ 
     headerData.CopyTo( buffer, 0 );
     // The 'sourceStream' is actually a MMF view stream being written to
     // by other processes.
     await sourceStream.WriteAsync( buffer, headerData.Length, pageSize );
     await tcpClient.GetStream( ).WriteAsync( buffer, 0, pageSize + pageHeaderSize ); 

     ++pageCounter;
}
```

This roughly shows how I'm writing data to the out going `TCP` stream. While I'm sending the data I monitor the network traffic via wire shark (which is running on the Windows 7 machine) and what I notice is that every packet transmitted is only `590` bytes (`TCP` header + payload). I have no idea why the packets are so small. This is causing a lot of unwanted network traffic.

Interestingly enough, another user here had a similar issue. [Why are TCP messages in my PC coming in frames of 590 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479482/why-are-tcp-messages-in-my-pc-coming-in-frames-of-590-bytes)

The user who answered that question suspects that there is another device in the middle with a much smaller 'MTU' size causing the `MTU` at both endpoints to adjust their size appropriately. But as I outlined above there is nothing else in the middle of the 2 hosts except for the 10 GbE switch..

I tagged this as `C#` for others to see if I'm doing something obviously wrong (but I don't think so as at the application level we only deal in `streams`).
I also tagged this as `networking` and `tcp-ip` to get advice from `IT` folks to see if there is some setting I haven't set in either of the 2 hosts or the switch.

What I don't get is why can I ping via `ping -l 8000 address` or `ping -f -l 8000 address` and see that correctly sized packets are being sent..

EDIT: As a side note, tomorrow morning I'm planning on disconnecting the 1GbE connections on both PC's.

Comment: TCP max size datagram is ~1500 bytes.  Routers and Servers can split and combine datagrams.  Windows use timers to pass datagrams to/from the Ethernet interface to application layer.  So if data is slow it will be split.  Also firewalls use port forwarding which also can split datagrams.

Comment: What is the MSS configured as?

Comment: @RonMaupin What ever the `nic`'s default value is. I'm unsure what that "default" max segment size is mind you. I'll have to check it when I get in tomorrow morning. That being said, would that be a network card configuration or a switch configuration or both?. Edit, just read Wiki's explanation on `MSS` and that sounds extremely promising.

Comment: The NIC doesn't know or care about the MSS, which is an upper-layer feature. You need to check how the OS has it set. What you refer to as a packet ("_TCP header + payload_") is actually a segment, which is the packet payload. The MSS controls the segment size, and if it is set to 590, then that is the maximum size that your segments will be.

Comment: If you are programatically relying on this size to be specific you are probably doing something wrong, or can solve your issue another way

Comment: @TheGeneral no, I’m not “programmatically” relying on the size of the packet in anyway. What I want a achieve is good throughout and reduced network overhead

Comment: Just because your network allows for larger packets, doesn't force the TCP stack to actually use them... in the case of the ping it is being forced at a low level. Also, ping utilizes a different protocol (ICMP) than TCP.

Comment: @fredrik I considered this as well but it’s nonsensical that the stack would arbitrarily select a packet size < 1500 MTU

Comment: Windows does autotuning - have you tried turning that off? https://serverfault.com/questions/46754/what-is-the-default-tcp-window-size-on-windows-server-2008

Comment: @fredrik No, I've never heard of that before. Once I get into work this morning i'll try to turn auto tuning off following the instructions in the link you posted. That being said it would strike me as odd if Windows selected a smaller Window size than < 64K but it's worth a check. I think my first plan of action will be to capture the initial handshake between my server and client and see if the `MSS` is lower than expected. I also want to check for additional settings in the switch that could impact packet size

Comment: @WBuck what did you find afterwards.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran So in this situation it was an issue with the packet size I had configured on the network switch. The packet size was a little bit smaller than it should have been. So, if I had the packet size in the switch set to 9014 MTU, setting the packet size to something larger than 9014 fixed the issue. I can't remember the exact MTU I used instead but it had to be larger than 9014.

Comment: Ok, good to know ! Thanks.